# How do I access the form element in JavaScript which contains popup window

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I access the input with `id="namesignup"` in javascript??

I tried using

```
console.log("Result :"+ $$('.popup-signup-email #namesignup'));
document.getElementById(namesignup)
```

Both are not working.. is there how to i access the data in the input??
Please help

```
<div data-page="signup" class="page no-navbar">
<!-- Begin: Page Content -->
<div class="page-content">
<div class="content-block"> </div>
<div class="content-block">
<p>
<button class="button big"><span>Connect with Facebook</span></button>
</p>
<p>
<button class="button"><span>Connect with Google</span></button>
</p>
<p>
<a href="#" class="button open-popup" data-popup=".popup-signup-email">
<span>Sign Up with Email</span>
</a>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- End: Page Content -->

<!-- Begin: Popup -->
<div class="popup tablet-fullscreen popup-signup-email">
<div class="toolbar">
<div class="toolbar-inner">
<div class="left">
<a href="#" class="link disabled"></a>
</div>
<div class="center">Sign Up</div>
<div class="right">
<a href="#" class="link close-popup">
</a>
</div></div></div>

<div class="container">
<div class="content-block"> </div>
<form name="signup-email" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="list-block no-hairlines">
<ul>
<li>
<div class="item-content">
<div class="item-media"></div>
<div class="item-inner">
<div class="item-input">
<input id="namesignup" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required />
</div>
```

Comment: what error you are getting? please post that info too..

Comment: It gives result: [object Object]

Comment: Or if i try to print the value in that like $$('.popup-signup-email #namesignup')).value it gives the result as undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you configured the jQuery & check with alias name. By default $ is alias name for jQuery. If properly configured, below code will work,

   $('#namesignup').val()

2) If you going with native JavaScript,

```
document.getElementById('namesignup').value
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Actually am trying to develop it from a whole template...This is a piece of code in a single page.. Will the templates have JQuery included by default.. or how do i know if Jquery is installed or not..

Comment: Thank U !! The second option u gave is working perfectly.. but how do i execute with jquery??

Comment: Finished installing Jquery and now its addded to the package.json now.. But still its now working ..console.log("Final :" + $("#namesignup").value); is not working.. It says Undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. This code looks for change in the `namesignup` and prints it in the console,

```html
<div data-page="signup" class="page no-navbar">
<!-- Begin: Page Content -->
<div class="page-content">
<div class="content-block"> </div>
<div class="content-block">
<p>
<button class="button big"><span>Connect with Facebook</span></button>
</p>
<p>
<button class="button"><span>Connect with Google</span></button>
</p>
<p>
<a href="#" class="button open-popup" data-popup=".popup-signup-email">
<span>Sign Up with Email</span>
</a>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- End: Page Content -->

<!-- Begin: Popup -->
<div class="popup tablet-fullscreen popup-signup-email">
<div class="toolbar">
<div class="toolbar-inner">
<div class="left">
<a href="#" class="link disabled"></a>
</div>
<div class="center">Sign Up</div>
<div class="right">
<a href="#" class="link close-popup">
</a>
</div></div></div>

<div class="container">
<div class="content-block"> </div>
<form name="signup-email" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="list-block no-hairlines">
<ul>
<li>
<div class="item-content">
<div class="item-media"></div>
<div class="item-inner">
<div class="item-input">
<input id="namesignup" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required />
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#namesignup").keyup(function(){
 console.log($("#namesignup").val());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned in later posts:

The `document.getElementById('namesignup').value` code must be worked but if you have multiple DOM with 'namesignup' Id then this code returns the first element value that has this id.

If you are using Google Chrome, press F12 -> go to element tab -> search 'namesignup'.

Be sure that you have one Element with this id.

Comment: Yes i have only one element with that id.. but as said in the prev answer the code isnt working..

Comment: no jquery is working for me..should i install jquery separately?

Answer (score 0):

1. in javascript use document.getElementById("namesignup").value
2. in jQuery use $("#namesignup").value()

Comment: document.getElementbyId is working for me but The jquery is still not working.. console.log("Final :" + $("#namesignup").value); not working.

Comment: $("#namesignup").value() it should return a value if you are using jquery.

What i can observed in your comment is like you are not using value as function

console.log("Final :" + $("#namesignup").value);// wrong

console.log("Final :" + $("#namesignup").value());//right one :)